# Select all rows of a table filtered by existence in another one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have a **drug** table holding id and name. On one of the pages I need to create a dropdown with all drugs names - although I cannot simply do:

```
SELECT id, name FROM drug;
```

In this case I want ONLY drugs which PZN codes exist in the **pharmacy_has_drug** table. To do this, I need to somehow "go through" **drug_product** table.

The structure:

[image]

- **drug_product.drug_id** holds reference to **drug.id**
- **pharmacy_has_drug.drug_PZN** holds reference do **drug_product.PZN**

How can I get the filtered drugs in this case?

Comment: SELECT ... WHERE EXISTS (select * from pharmacy_has_drug.drug_PZN  = drug_product.PZN)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name
FROM drug d
INNER JOIN drug_product p ON d.id=p.drug_id
WHERE p.drug= 62732
```

Or if you need a condition on the pharmacy_has_drug table:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name
FROM drug d
INNER JOIN drug_product p ON d.id=p.drug_id
INNER JOIN pharmacy_has_drug ph ON ph.drug_PZN=d.PZN
WHERE ph.pharmacy_id= 12
```

Edit:
Just remove the where clause if not needed.
The inner join is enough in your case.

```
SELECT d.id, d.name
FROM drug d
INNER JOIN drug_product p ON d.id=p.drug_id
INNER JOIN pharmacy_has_drug ph ON ph.drug_PZN=d.PZN
```

Comment: With this approach (using `WHERE` with specific value) I would need to perform this query 300 times if I have 300 drugs. Not really efficient. I was wondering if this can be done in one query: select each drug, but only if it's referenced in **pharmacy_has_drug**.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know whether a record exists use EXISTS:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM drug
WHERE EXISTS
(
  select *
  from drug_product dp 
  join pharmacy_has_drug phd on phd.drug_pzn = dp.pzn
  where dp.drug_id = drug.id
);
```

Or an IN clause:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM drug
WHERE id IN
(
  select dp.drug_id
  from drug_product dp 
  join pharmacy_has_drug phd on phd.drug_pzn = dp.pzn
);
```

You can even split the single steps: 1. Give me all PZNs in pharmacy_has_drug. 2. Give me all matching drug IDs from drug_product. 3. Select the matching drugs.

```
select id, name from drug
where id in
(
  select drug_id from drug_product
  where pzn in
  (
    select drug_pzn from pharmacy_has_drug
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.id, d.name
FROM drug d
  INNER JOIN drug_product p ON p.drug_id = d.id
  INNER JOIN pharmacy_has_drug ph ON ph.drug_PZN = p.PZN
```

It analyzes all the rows from table `drugs`. For each one it checks the table `drug_product` for a matching row. If no such row can be found then the row from table `drugs` is ignored (because of the `INNER` JOIN). If one or more matching rows are found then for each of them it checks the table `pharmacy_has_drug` for rows matching `drug_product`.`PZN`. Again, if no matching row is found then the partial result already computed is discarded and it advances to the next row from `drugs`.
If a matching row is found in `pharmacy_has_drug` then one or more rows will be appended to the result set; when a drug can be found in many pharmacies then a row is computed for each combination but, because only columns from table `drugs` appear in the `SELECT` clause then the final result set will contain duplicates.

The `DISTINCT` keyword in the `SELECT` clause removes the duplicates and makes the query run faster (because the `DISTINCT` optimization makes the engine stop searching for other rows after the first match).